# Best way to install Desura

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to install Desura and to keep up to date.

First I tried this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/desurium-stable
```

but apparently it's not available anymore. I get the error `Cannot add PPA .. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Then I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/desurium
```

I got [this](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/ubuntu/desurium):

```
Bad Juju the new owner of Desura has filed for bankruptcy. This means that this repository is no longer maintained.

The latest source from the project can be obtained from:
https://github.com/desura/desura-app
The old Desurium code:
https://github.com/desura/Desurium
Unfortunately this code is not working for Linux. This repository host the last working snapshot (with few patches) of legacy Desurium.

System versions: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

To install Desurium do following commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/desurium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install desurium
```

...so I don't get it; should I install it from github or from here? *OR* should I just download the tar.gz from [their website](http://www.desura.com/)? *(button at the top right)*

Comment: I went to the PPA you linked and I think what you should do is to download the GitHub repo at https://github.com/desura/desura-app and compile from source.